# Rails4 - How to force a user to update a field in his/her profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user moder with a field "Introduction" which has to be filled along with other details when the user activates his/her account.
I want to force the users to fill the introduction.

I have this line in my user controller.

```
validates :intro,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 300 }, on: :update
```

But the users are able to click on other links on the webpage and use the website without filling the intro. I want to force them to update their profile and not let them access the website if they have not filled their profile properly.

I tried this in my application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404

  include SessionsHelper

  before_filter :completed_profile      

  private    

    def completed_profile
      if logged_in?

        if current_user.user_languages.count == 0 || current_user.user_learnings.count == 0 

          if current_user.intro.blank?
            flash[:introdiv] = "Introduction can't be blank."
          end

          redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
        end
      end
    end         
end
```

But it is not correct. It redirects them to update the profile. But when they try to update intro field and save, it again redirects to update profile because the intro has not been saved.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: In the `completed_profile` method you have no conditions to check if the intro is blank or not only a condition to check if the user is logged in or not and redirect so it will always redirect to the edit user page wether they have complete profile or not.

Comment: I think uncomment the line in your filter code that code will work

Comment: With uncommenting move the redirect inside the if condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `skip_before_filter` on the edit and update actions

```
class UsersController < ApplicaitonController
  skip_before_filter :completed_profile, only: [:edit, :update]
end
```